# Does the phrase exclusive possession actually denote a covenant or "implied term" of tenancies which landlords must respect, as is often claimed?

Tags: england-and-wales, common-law, tenancy

Or is it more a taxonomical device used to deduce as to whether or not a given agreement for accommodation is legally to be deemed a tenancy?

In other words, considering the following quotation from the law lords' decision...

> "The manufacture of a five pronged implement for manual digging results in a fork even if the manufacturer, unfamiliar with the English language, insists that he intended to make and has made a spade,

...can it be said that exclusive possession is more akin to the number of prongs required to render something as that which may be *described* as a fork, rather than any legal stipulations as to the *prescribed* conduct surrounding forks?

Comment: Can you please be more specific as to the problem or issue you want addressed, and the context in which it arises.

Comment: I don't see how I could be. It is genuinely a general question about the law, striving to understand the law itself. Genuinely not sarcastic, and I know that (fortunately and rightly so) the rule is sometimes disregarded but like, I thought this site wasn't supposed to be for specific legal advice but only understanding of law?

Comment: In any case I can share the context in which the question was formed in my mind, although it must be stated that the question stands in its own right independently of its mental origin. Many sites and blog articles claim that all tenancies implicitly feature exclusive possession. A recent UKHL case link however suggests to me rather that it is the other way around: if you are effectively granted exclusive possession then what you have is a tenancy along with all the protections and regulatory provisions that apply to and go along with that. In other words, the term exclusive possession isn't

Comment: Such a legal protection itself per se, but a factual condition which establishes and affords various other protections.

Comment: Yet the idea that exclusive possession is an implied contract term of certain types of contracts determined in other ways is widely repeated. I was told that by a professional advisor with whom I was speaking on behalf of a friend, because what they have is an AST, then they are entitled to exclusive possession which amounts to total control over who stays and goes from the space. As such, notifying the tenant that one will enter the premises without obtaining explicitly affirmed permission from them is unacceptable grounds for entering the premises, regardless of what the contract may or may

Comment: Follows on from this question: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/83677/what-is-the-legal-basis-origin-for-the-covenant-of-exclusive-possession

Comment: Not say. This understanding is oft-repeated in diverse fora, but seemingly never with citations to any specific legally authoritative source (statute or case law). Sometimes there is a vague citation given to attribute the covenant or alternatively "implied term" simply to "common law," but surely someone somewhere would be able to offer a reference to some judge somewhere in some cases since recorded judicial history would have laid out, elaborated and employed this concept in a binding precedent ruling where we could see it. But instead all I'm able to find in the way of authoritative sauces

Comment: On the concept is this UKHL opinion which seems to employ it as a device for identifying where a tenancy has arisen, rather than declaring or upholding it as a binding term of all common law tenancies where they have been established and identified as such.

Comment: Thanks for that link, Steve. The case referred to then would be Street v. Mountford. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_v_Mountford

Comment: https://landlordlawblog.co.uk/2018/07/04/six-important-elements-tenancy-lease/

Comment: The buzz word in U.S. landlord-tenant law is usually "quiet possession".

Comment: @ohwilleke are you thinking of "quiet enjoyment"?

Answer (score 0):

### Both

A tenant has the right of exclusive possession.

A person who has a right of exclusive possession is a tenant.

Exclusive possession is so [fundamental](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_v_Mountford) to a lease that one implies the other.

Comment: Can you cite any support for that either of these would imply the other rather than just in one direction?

Comment: @JosephP. I did

Comment: Okay well at best it is a link-only citation. A more specific reference or quotation or excerpt would be appreciated especially as I have already quoted directly from that decision in my question and proposed the impression that it suggests the opposite of what you claim so citing the same link back without explaining how in fact it supports the opposite of what I had thought it does is basically just saying "I know you are but what am I?"